# How do I add KendoUI Validator attributes to fields generated by HTML helper functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement a form using the KendoUI Validator and it requires attribute decoration of the form fields that need to be validated.

Below is the desired html that I want to render:

```
<input type="email" required>
```

How can I render this html using `@Html.EditorFor` through the Razor view engine?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a custom template, using the [EditorFor override that takes the name of a template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).  Add a custom [template to your project as decribed by Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), and then you can customize the appearance for your email fields using this template.  The basic setup is:

In the views folder, create an EditorTemplates folder in your view's controller folder (for instance, for HomeController, create the folder in Views/Home/EditorTemplates).  Add a template that will appear, with the model defined as the value being edited, and add the markup you want as mentioned above.

Then you just need to use `Html.EditorFor(i => i.X, "NameofTemplate");`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you are going to edit an email (on which you want to enable validation) you will need to use TextBox.

To generate input of type e-mail you can set its html attributes like this:

```
@(Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { type="email"}))
```